# Доступ к View элементам сторонней разметки

Tags: java, android

Приветствую. Я использую `DialogFragment` который вызывается из главного `Activity`, в самом `DialogFragment` я использую собственную разметку, в которой реализован `ListView`, заполняю я `ListView` следующим образом.

```
try {
        SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DBSQLiteOpenHelper(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("MYTABLE", new String[] {"_id", "TEXT1",
                "TEXT2"}, null, null, null, null, null);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_heads_item,
                cursor,
                new String[] {"TEXT1", "TEXT2"},
                new int[] {R.id.myText1, R.id.myText2});

        dialog_heads_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "База данных недоступна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Все работает отлично, однако у меня появилась потребность работать с `View` элементами разметки `R.layout.list_heads_item` динамически. Так как эта разметка не является разметкой подключаемой непосредственно к `DialogFragment`, то каким образом я могу получить доступ к её `View` элементам в `DialogFragment` чтобы динамически их менять?

Answer (score 0):

`SipleCursorAdapter` не позволит тебе получить доступ к `View` элемента списка для его модификации

Единственно верным решением будет создать свой более сложный адаптер унаследовавшись от `CursorAdaper`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/167620)

Comment: Почему не является? А теперь?

Comment: теперь пойдёт )